# switch the value of the app setting for live or testing environment

Tags: windows-phone-7

When creating a web application, we can set the app setting on web.config. We can easily change the valule of the app.setting on the web.config. We can switch the web.config file for live or testing environment. How about on the Windows phone app? May I use the text file instead of the web.config? When the app load, I read the content on the text file, so I can replaced it easily for live. Is it a good idea to do? If not, would you give me an idea how to swithch the value of the setting for testing or live.

Answer (score 0):

I use something similar. I have an app.config file which is a xml file with my own structure. I have a class that loads and uses it. You can create app.config and app.config-debug and load them like

```
#if DEBUG
    //load app.config-debug
else
    //load app.config
#endif
```

when you app starts.